# Rails path for images with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, image, twitter-bootstrap

Hello i want to use a boostrap (in my rails app) Heroes with an image and to use it i need to use img and not image_tag but that dont find my image. Here the code

```
<div class="px-4 pt-5 my-5 text-center border-bottom">
    <h1 class="display-4 fw-bold">Centered screenshot</h1>
    <div class="col-lg-6 mx-auto">
      <p class="lead mb-4">Quickly design and customize responsive mobile-first sites with Bootstrap, the world’s most popular front-end open source toolkit, featuring Sass variables and mixins, responsive grid system, extensive prebuilt components, and powerful JavaScript plugins.</p>
      <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-sm-flex justify-content-sm-center mb-5">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg px-4 me-sm-3">Primary button</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-lg px-4">Secondary</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overflow-hidden" style="max-height: 30vh;">
      <div class="container px-5">
        <img src="/images/test2.png" class="img-fluid border rounded-3 shadow-lg mb-4" alt="Example image" width="700" height="500" loading="lazy">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I've tested also src="test2.png" , "/test2.png" etc...

The problem with image_tag I can't add the width, height or loading parameters.

Comment: please share a working example like codepen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `image_path` :

```
<img src="<%= image_path('test2.png') %>" class="img-fluid border rounded-3 shadow-lg mb-4" alt="Example image" width="700" height="500" loading="lazy">
```

Note that you can also use `image_tag` and specify any parameter including width, height, style, class ... see examples in [https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag](https://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_path)